# Buffer/stream to read a subset of a file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I have written a class which parses the header segment of data file (for storing scientific instrument data) and collects things like offsets to various data segments within the file. The actual data is obtained through various methods which read and parse the data segments.

The problem I'm running into is that there is a segment defined for vendor-specific, unstructured data. Since there's nothing to parse I just need my method to return raw binary data. However this segment could be very large so I don't just want to read it all at once and return a single `bytes` object.

What I'd like to do is have the method return an `io.BufferedReader` object or similar into the file that only reads between a beginning and end offset. I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this using the builtin IO classes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You inherit all of the class methods from IOBase so you can absolutely call reader.seek(byte_offset) to skip to this byte position in the stream. However from there you will have to manually track the bytes you have read until you get to the max offset you are reading to. The start offset for seek() will of course have to be known beforehand as will the ending byte offset. Some example code follows (assuming a start offset of byte 250):

```
import io

stream = io.open("file.txt", "r")
buffered_reader = io.BufferedReader(stream)
# set the stream to byte 250
buffered_reader.seek(250)
# read up to byte 750 (500 bytes from position 250)
data = buffered_reader.read(500)
```

Of course, if this header is dynamically sized... You will have to scan to determine start positions which means reading line by line.

Comment: This question is more about the API - I would like the method to return a stream which reads from only that segment of the file, without the caller needing to worry about what the actual offsets are.

Comment: Assuming that the header is dynamic in construction? if so gotta go with scanning to determine starting point. There is no magic API call on the io module or its classes that will automatically know where to start on every file given if the starting point is dependent on a specific header length.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase the question very clearly. I have already parsed the file and know where the offsets are. I want this to be entirely transparent to any other code using the module so that it can simply ask for a stream to the data segment without knowing anything about the file format or internals.